# Bash: Calculate 7am of next day

Tags: bash, date

I would like to calculate the time for 7am of the next day with the bash. (I want to use it to restart the computer with `rtcwake`)

According to the man page of `date` I should use `%s` to get a unix timestamp. But how do I get if of the next day? (Or 7am of today => add one day)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-d` option

```
date -d '7:00 tomorrow' +%s
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#date-invocation
https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/coreutils.html#Relative-items-in-date-strings